# Como puedo bloquear un usuario al 3 intento y tener un usuario administrador que me lo permita desbloquear

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

estoy haciendo un login de usuario y contraseña. Me piden que si un usuario hizo 3 intentos fallidos para loguearse se le bloquee la cuenta y a su vez tener un usuario que sea como administrador de todos los usuarios que al entrar a esa cuenta me muestre las cuentas bloqueadas y pueda desbloquearlas. Esta es el codigo PHP mio `

```
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];    
$clave = $_POST['clave'];

// Conectar a la base de datos

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test"); //Servidor, usuario, clave, base de datos

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM bdprueba WHERE usuario='$usuario' and clave='$clave'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if ($filas > 0) { //Es decir si hay un dato
    header("location:bienvenido.html");
} else {
    echo "Error en la autentificacion";
    header("location:index.html");

}
mysqli_free_result($resultado) //Liberar el espacio de los resultados
// mysqli_close($conexion) // Cerrar la conexion para que no consuma recurso.
```

?>`

y este seria el codigo html (super basico) para mostrar el login 
`

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index2.php" method="POST">
        Usuario: <br> <input type='text' name='usuario'><br>
        Clave: <br> <input type='password' name='clave'><br>
        <input type='submit' value='Ingresar'>
    </form>
    <style>
    
    </style>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, podrias especificar cual fue el problema que tuviste al tratar de implementar esto que te pidieron?

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he hecho con variables de sesion `$_SESSION["fails"]` , asi cuando de lado del script las credenciales están mal con `if / else` controlo cuando ir incrementando mi variable `$_SESSION["fails"]` y cuando `$_SESSION["fails"] == 3` realizo el bloqueo de la cuenta, es importante revisar si `$_SESSION["fails"]` ya ha sido seteado ya sea con `isset (PHP5 - PHP7)` o con `?? de PHP7.4` para evitar estarle asignando un valor.

En tu código en esta parte es donde iría:

```
if ($filas > 0) { //Es decir si hay un dato
    header("location:bienvenido.html");
} else {
    echo "Error en la autentificación";
    $_SESSION['fails'] = $_SESSION['fails'] + 1;
    if ($_SESSION['fails'] == 3 ) {
       // Aqui realizas el bloqueo de la cuenta
    }
    header("location:index.html");
}
```

Tambien en tu tabla, debes agregar algo que indique que la cuenta esta bloqueada, agregando un campo bool por ejemplo "isBlocked", asi cuando consultes los campos al loguear puedas saber si esta bloqueada o no.

Ya la parte del usuario que ve todo, tendrias que crear roles para tus usuarios y que solo el que tenga un rol `admin` pueda ver el listado de usuarios y hacer modificaciones sobre cualquier usuario.

Comment: Me sirvio sus respuestas. Muchas gracias!! Lo que me faltaría es solamente como hacer de forma simple lo del usuario que sea administrador y poder desbloquear los usuarios a traves de el administrador.

Comment: @LautaroRodriguez ya te han respondido, tu tabla usuario debe tener un campo rol, que te garantiza la separación de responsabilidades (permisos sobre las diferentes funcionalidades), entonces estarías chequeando el rol del usuario y si es "admin" pues tendrá acceso a la lista de usuarios bloqueados y además acceso a la funcionalidad desbloquear cuenta. En cualquier caso son opiniones y no vale la pena continuar violando las políticas de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que tener en la base de datos por ejemplo una tabla usuarios y otra tabla perfiles, puedes usar un contador y cuando el contador sea igual a 4 actualizas el estado del usuario como inhabilitado y validas que en el inicio de sesión solo los usuarios activos pueden acceder.

Cuando un usuario se loguea con perfil de admin se le puede proveer una opción en algún menu de tu app para que le cambie el estado al usuario siguiendo x procedimiento, confirmando con contraseña, aprobando una solicitud, etc.

Comment: Me sirvio sus respuestas. Muchas gracias!! Lo que me faltaría es solamente como hacer de forma simple lo del usuario que sea administrador y poder desbloquear los usuarios a traves de el administrador.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo utilizando variables de session y agregando una columna `user_block` a tu tabla de tipo bit ejemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE `bdprueba` ADD `user_block` BIT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1' AFTER `usuario`;
```

ahora el codigo nos quedaria asi:

```
session_start();
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];    
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
// si esta definida sera igual a intentos en caso contrario sera 0
$_SESSION["intentos"] = isset($_SESSION["intentos"]) ? $_SESSION["intentos"] : 0;
// Conectar a la base de datos

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test"); //Servidor, usuario, clave, base de datos

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM bdprueba WHERE usuario='$usuario' and clave='$clave' and user_block=1";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if ($filas > 0) { //Es decir si hay un dato
    // si todo esta correcto volvera a ser 0
    $_SESSION["intentos"] = 0;
    header("location:bienvenido.html");
} else {
    echo "Error en la autentificacion";
    $_SESSION["intentos"]++; // aumentamos en 1 los intentos

    header("location:index.html");
}

if($_SESSION["intentos"] >=3){
  // actualizamos el campo mostrar para que no se puede iniciar session
  $consulta = "UPDATE bdprueba SET user_block=0 WHERE usuario='$usuario'";

  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
  echo "demaciados intentos de incio de session usuario {$usuario} bloqueado!";
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado) //Liberar el espacio de los resultados
// mysqli_close($conexion) // Cerrar la conexion para que no consuma recurso.
```

Comment: Me sirvio sus respuestas. Muchas gracias!! Lo que me faltaría es solamente como hacer de forma simple lo del usuario que sea administrador y poder desbloquear los usuarios a traves de el administrador.